# Modify files after Bower install

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bower

I manually downloaded the css and js files for an angular module ([**Click here**](https://github.com/awerlang/angular-responsive-tables)).

I made a minor change to the css (changed max-width for media query):

```
Original:
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {...}

Modified:
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {...}
```

If I fetch the latest version using Bower, it will override my change. So I am wondering if it is possible to get the latest version, but somehow either automatically change the max-width back, or if there is a way to override the query's screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

- use just the JS from Bower and bundle your customized CSS in your project
- or set up your build process to patch the Bower-downloaded CSS (such as search-and-replacing `max-width: 800px` with `max-width: 999px`).

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to modify it during the build process?

Comment: Depends on the tools you're using. For a gulp workflow, I'd probably write a postcss plugin that targets that particular media query. Though to be honest, a simple search-and-replace would do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fork the original project so you have full control over the changes.

- (+) Full control over the package
- (-) You have to maintain the code itself (it won't upgrade itself)